# Fetch data in many-many relationship in a single row

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-orm, mysql-python

These are my models

**Team Table**

```
class Team(CommonModel):
    ****Other Fields****
    name = models.CharField()
    game = models.ManyToManyField(Game, through='Team_Game')
```

**Mapper Table**

```
class Team_Game(CommonModel):
    game = models.ForeignKey(Game, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    team = models.ForeignKey(Team, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    status = models.SmallIntegerField(default=1)
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'team_game'
```

**Game Table**

```
class Game(CommonModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=False, null=False, unique=True)
    status = models.SmallIntegerField(default=1)
```

I want to retrieve team with id 1 and game associated with it
Expected data: team.name, other_team_cols, [game_id1, game_id2]

Query:

```
team_data = Team.objects.filter(id=1).values('id', 'name', 'game__name')
```

Output:

```
[
    {
        "id": "1",
        "name": 'abc',
        "game__name": "game1"
    },
    {
        "_packageID": "1",
        "name": "def",
        "game__name": "game2"
    }
]
```

Expected Output:

```
{
        "id": "1",
        "name": 'abc',
        "game__name": ["gam1", "gam2"]
}
```

Comment: SQL generated by your query does not aggregate games' names into an array. If you use postgres then you can use `ArrayAgg` (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/postgres/aggregates/#arrayagg).
So the query could look like `Team.objects.filter(id=1).aggregate(game__names=ArrayAgg('game__name')).values('id', 'name', 'game__names')`. I do not know if naming output of array aggregation like `game__name` will not interfere with model field somehow.

Answer (score 0):

Declare a array iterate the loop and store the game__name values[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/72OyB.png)

```
team_data=[
    {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "abc",
        "game__name": "game1"
    },
    {
        "_packageID": "1",
        "names": "def",
        "game__name": "game2"
    }
]
arr=[]

for report in team_data :
    
    arr.append(report["game__name"])
print(arr)
```